# Approximating Chi squared distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A machine in a heavy equipment-factory produces steel rods of length Y , where Y
is a normally distributed random variable with mean 6cm inches and variance $\frac{1}{4} cm^2 $. Thecost C of repairing a rod that is not exactly 6 inches is given by$ C = 4(Y - 6)^2$
. If 50 rods
with independent lengths are produced in a given day, approximate the probability that
the total cost for repairs for that day exceeds 48.

Alright, first things first: C looks like $\chi^2(1)$ because that 6 and 4 are not there without a reason:
$$
\begin{align}
C &= 4(Y-6)^2 &
\\ &=\frac{(Y-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2} &\mu=6, \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{4}
\end{align}
$$
so $C\sim\chi^2(1)$, because $Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$
So we can assume that $50* \chi^2(1) = \chi^2(50)$ (is that a good way of saying that? )

So lets say $X = \chi^2(50)$ Our new question is: (after this point im lost)
$$
\begin{align}
P(X>48) &= P(\frac{X-50}{100} >\frac{48-50}{100})
\\&\approx P(Z>-0.02) = P(Z<0.02)
\\&\approx 0.5080
\end{align}
$$
Does this seem a reasonable way of doing things? I have no way of checking

Comment: "*with mean 6cm inches*" cm-inches is a new one on me. Please make your use of units consistent. "*$50 \chi^2(1) = \chi^2(50)$*" -- this statement is false. Are you confusing adding 50 random variables with multiplying one random variable by 50?

Comment: actualyl yeah, that was wrong in the exercise. And you are right i am confusing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y_i$ are iid $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{50}\left(\frac{Y_i-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\sim \chi^2(50)
$$
as you indicated. Remember that the sum of $n$ squared independent standard normal variables is $\chi^2$ distributed with $n$ degrees of freedom. So you don't need to go via $C\sim \chi^2(1)$, you may go there immediately.

As this is a sum of independently and identically distributed random variables and $n$ is reasonably 'large', we may use the Central Limit Theorem for a normal approximation, as you also have done. However, you need to remember that the standardization is done in the following way:

$$
Pr(X < c)=Pr\left(\frac{X-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}<\frac{c-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}\right)=Pr\left(Z<\frac{c-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}\right)
$$
where we use the standard deviation $\sigma$. Note that the *variance* of a $\chi^2(v)$ is $2v$, meaning that the standard deviation must be $\sigma=\sqrt{2v}$. So you are almost there, you just have to cross the line, so to speak.

Comment: So my only fault was doing $\sigma = 2v$ instead of $\sigma \sqrt{2v}$